# Javascript allow specific input

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Javascript Regex that will allow only `hebrew` or `english`, and only the characters `" ' -`

I reached this one:

```
        var allowed = /^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+|["'])$/i;
        if(!allowed.exec(name)) {
           alert('not allowed');
        }
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Why don't you tell us whats wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know, what _is_ wrong with it? Are you getting an error, or false positives, or false negatives, or...? Why don't you put all of the permissible characters in the same `[]` instead of using the or conditions? Also, you may like to say `if (!allowed.test(name))` rather than `.exec()`.

Answer (score 3):

> whats wrong with it[?]

What immediately jumps out at me:

- Your regex doesn't specify the `-` is allowed
- You use `\w`, which allows `_` as well as `A-Za-z`.
- You use `exec` when you should use `test`.
- The `|` expressions are unnecessary, use a unified character class

Try the following:

```
var allowed = /^[-A-Z"'\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+$/i;
if(!allowed.test(name)) {
    alert('not allowed');
}
```

Or, if you want to make sure it is English *or* Hebrew:

```
/^(?:[-A-Z"']+|[-"'\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+)$/i
```

If that doesn't help you, you need to be more specific about why it isn't suitable for you.

Comment: The `|` are not only unnecessary, they affect the match so that it *either* matches all-Hebrew characters *or*  all-ASCII alphanumerics *or* quotes but nothing else.